# how to calculate gst value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have sales transaction in my project, I want to calculate total amount with and without `gst`.
[image]

I keep a `textbox` to enter the `gst` value if we want we enter the `gst` value for the particular product while auto calculated when key ups if we don't want to include the total amount to be calculated automatically.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gst').keyup(function(ev) {
    var reeta = price * qty;
    var tot_price = (reeta * gst / 100) + reeta ;
    var divobj = document.getElementById('tot_amount');
    divobj.value = tot_price;
  });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php echo ++$counter; ?>
  </td>
  <td class="record">
    <?php echo $row['prod_name'];?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="qty" type="text" readonly value="<?php echo $row['qty'];?">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="price" type="text" readonly value="<?php echo number_format($row['price'], 2);?>">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="gst" type="text"><br><br>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="tot_amount" readonly id="tot_amount" type="text" ><br><br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Thus I need to calculate `gst` based on the rate entered `gstrate` field. Can anyone give me a hand? Most of the formulas calculate `gst` amount and add it to subtotal but I have no chance to do that.

Comment: I don't see any `gstrate` field

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: calculation is not work, it's shows NaN But i don't know what i miss. please guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you have used ids, here is the example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gst').keyup(function(ev) {
    var gst = $("#gst").val();
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var qty = $("#qty").val();
    var reeta = price * qty;
    var tot_price = (reeta * gst / 100) + reeta;
    var divobj = document.getElementById('tot_amount');
    divobj.value = tot_price;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    1
  </td>
  <td class="record">
    AMK
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="qty" type="text" readonly value="2">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="price" type="text" readonly value="144.00">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="gst" type="text"><br><br>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="tot_amount" readonly id="tot_amount" type="text"><br><br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it:

```
$('#gst').keyup(function(ev) {
    var price = $('#price').val();
    var qty = $('#qty').val();
    var gst = $(this).val();
    var reeta = price * qty;
    var tot_price = (reeta * gst / 100) + reeta ;
    $('#total').val(tot_price);
  });
```

Check my working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/nkvhz758/

I better suggest you to make change on focus event of result so it sounds proper.

Comment: Thank you for, It's working perfectly when i am work separate file, But If i am work in my application is not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This Code It's Is Work..!
>
> **This Code is work any value enter time change total it is dynamic code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gst').keyup(function(ev) {
    cal();
  });
  $('#price').keyup(function(ev) {
    cal();
  });
  $('#qty').keyup(function(ev) {
    cal();
  });
  function cal()
  {
    var gst = 0;
    var price = 0;
    var qty = 0;
    var amount = 0;    
    var total = 0;
    qty = $('#qty').val();
    if(qty > 0) 
    {
      price = $("#price").val();
      if(price > 0)
      {
        amount = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price)
        gst = $("#gst").val();
        if(gst > 0)
        {
          gst =  parseFloat(amount) * parseFloat(gst) / 100;
          total = parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat(gst);
          $('#total').val(total);          
          $('#total_gst').val(gst);
        }
        else
        {
          total = parseFloat(amount);
          $('#total').val(total);
          $('#total_gst').val(gst);
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
});
```

```css
table td
 { 
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td class="record">AMK</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Enter The Qty</td>
     <td><input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="qty" type="text"  value="10"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Enter The Price</td>
     <td><input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="price" type="text"  value="100"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Enter The GST</td>
     <td><input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="gst" type="text" value="0"></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Total The GST</td>
     <td><input class="w3-input w3-border" name="pages" id="total_gst" type="text" value="0" disabled></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Total</td>
     <td><input class="w3-input w3-border" name="total" disabled id="total" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If i add the default values on gst rate how it will be